# why does openssl_x509_fingerprint gives different value from original?

Tags: php, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I'm working on a php program that will verify a digital signature.  I'm testing with an example (valid) certificate, and decrypting the digital signature, this gives me the sha256 digest which I am trying to match:

```
$Cert1 = file_get_contents('CERT1/cert_array.json'); // TEST CERT DATA
$Cert1 = json_decode($Cert1, true);
$PublicKey = file_get_contents('CERT2/public_key_rsa.pem'); // CA CERT PUBLIC KEY
openssl_public_decrypt(hex2bin($Cert1['DigitalSignature']), $DecryptedDigitalSignature, $PublicKey, OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING); // DECRYPT SIGNATURE USING CA PUBLIC KEY
print('decrypted digital signature:' . bin2hex($DecryptedDigitalSignature) . "\n\n"); // PRINT RESULTS
```

This outputs the following:

```
decrypted digital signature:
3031300d0609608648016503040201050004200bf3dcf2340b972e97fe3c8493e11eeee01f298939734690d0b4e79e1f5701b4
```

There is some padding on the left, I now split this up to get the sha256 digest:

```
3031300d060960864801650304020105000420 // PADDING
0bf3dcf2340b972e97fe3c8493e11eeee01f298939734690d0b4e79e1f5701b4  // SHA256 DIGEST
```

Ok, so now I have my sha 256 digest, so I now wish to use the openssl_x509_fingerprint function on the same cert (CERT1) to create my own sha256 digest.  This should match the digest that I already extracted from the cert from above.  I use this code:

```
$Cert1 = file_get_contents('CERT1/cert.crt'); // THE CERT IN VALID x509 FORMAT
print(openssl_x509_fingerprint($Cert1, 'sha256'));
```

I get the following result:

```
d74157547fb287694b95b2533588c71f8706b0960e023fc4317f4f9a49ad2721
```

So, my question is, why am I getting "d74157547fb287694b95b2533588c71f8706b0960e023fc4317f4f9a49ad2721" and not "0bf3dcf2340b972e97fe3c8493e11eeee01f298939734690d0b4e79e1f5701b4"?

Comment: The fingerprint of a certificate is not the same as the signature.  The fingerprint is instead a hash over the full certificate content, which includes the signature. So the result differ since you compare different things.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion on the easiest way to generate the signature digest?